# How do multiply the nabla operator by $f$?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I have the function $f=\{x,-y,0\}$, and each of the derivatives together result in $\{1,-1,0\}$. To calculate the divergence $\nabla\cdot$ of $f$ I'd have to do the dot (scalar) product of partial derivatives with $f$, while for the curl $\nabla\times$ I have to do the cross product. I

I know that the curl is $\{0,0,2\}$ but I do not really understand how this result comes up: the cross product of the partial derivatives with $f$ results in something like $\{0,0,x+y\}$.

Please bear in mind I'm very new to this topic and no one has taught me this, so *it would help if someone could point out what has to be multiplied by what exactly*. Thanks.

Comment: I noticed that I made a typo that changed the task into another one with the curl really being {0,0,0} like the comments say!

Answer (score 0):

So what I understand is that you have trouble calculating the curl of a given vector field
$$
F_x = x\qquad F_y=-y \qquad F_z = 0
$$
In Wikipedia, for example, you can find the quite straightforward formula for the curl: 
$$
\nabla\times F = \left( \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial z}\ \right) \hat{i}
+\left( \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial x}\ \right) \hat{j}
+ \left( \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y}\ \right) \hat{k}
$$
As you see, there are no terms $\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x}$ or $\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y}$, so therefore the curl is zero.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer, Maybe I didn't word it so clearly but I do know the Formula and also the curl is a Vector {0,0,2}  . I was asking for a calculation of that Vector cross products in detail not with the Formula Units but the actual digits that apply for this example.

Comment: Is the fector field $F$ correct? Because I'm quite convinced that the curl is zero (more specifically, it's $\left\{ 0, 0, 0 \right\}$ and independent of the values of $x, y, z$). But you say that you "know that the curl is $\left\{ 0, 0, 2 \right\}$" - how do you get this result? And how did you get the result $\left\{ 0, 0, x+y \right\}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the definitions. We have a vector field (vector-valued function) $$\bbox { \begin{aligned}
\mathbf{F}(x, y, z) &= \bigr ( X(x, y, z) , Y(x, y, z) , Z(x, y, z) \bigr ) \\
\; &= X(x,y,z) \hat{\mathbf{e}}_x + Y(x, y, z) \hat{\mathbf{e}}_y + Z(x, y, z) \hat{\mathbf{e}}_z \\
\end{aligned} }$$
where $X(x, y, z)$, $Y(x, y, z)$ and $Z(x, y, z)$ are scalar functions, and $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_x$, $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_y$, and $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_z$ are the standard unit vectors in the directions of the $x$, $y$, and $z$ coordinates, respectively.

Divergence is defined as
$$\bbox {
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}(x, y, z) = \frac{\partial X(x, y, z)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial Y(x, y, z)}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial Z(x, y, z)}{\partial z}
}$$
and curl is defined as
$$\bbox { \begin{aligned}
\nabla \times \mathbf{F}(x, y, z) &= \left [ \begin{matrix}
\hat{\mathbf{e}}_x & \hat{\mathbf{e}}_y & \hat{\mathbf{e}}_z \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
X(x,y,z) & Y(x,y,z) & Z(x,y,z) \\
\end{matrix} \right ] \\
\; &= \hat{\mathbf{e}}_x \left (
\frac{\partial Z(x,y,z)}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial Y(x,y,z)}{\partial z}
\right ) \\
\; &\, + \hat{\mathbf{e}}_y \left (
\frac{\partial X(x,y,z)}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial Z(x,y,z)}{\partial x}
\right ) \\
\; &\, + \hat{\mathbf{e}}_z \left (
\frac{\partial Y(x,y,z)}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial X(x,y,z)}{\partial y}
\right ) \\
\end{aligned} }$$
These are the same things if you wrote $\nabla = \left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} , \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \right )$ and did the dot and cross products, respectively.

---

In OP's case, $X(x,y,z) = x$, $Y(x,y,z) = -y$, and $Z(x,y,z) = 0$.

For divergence, that gives us
$$\bbox{ \begin{aligned}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}(x, y, z) &= \frac{d x}{d x} + \frac{d(-y)}{d y} + 0 \\
\; &= 1 - 1 \\
\; &= 0 \\
\end{aligned} }$$

For curl, we have
$$\bbox{ \begin{aligned}
\nabla \times \mathbf{F}(x, y, z) &= \hat{\mathbf{e}}_x \bigr ( 0 - 0 \bigr ) \\
\; & + \, \hat{\mathbf{e}}_y \bigr ( 0 - 0 \bigr ) \\
\; & + \, \hat{\mathbf{e}}_z \bigr ( 0 - 0 \bigr ) \\
\; & = \bigr ( 0, 0, 0 \bigr ) \\
\end{aligned} }$$

---

Note that Maple agrees,

```
>  with(VectorCalculus):
>  f := VectorField(<x,-y,0>, 'cartesian'[x, y, z]):
>  Divergence(f);
        0
>  Curl(f);
           _       _       _
        (0)e  + (0)e  + (0)e
            x       y       z
```

and so does SageMath:

```
sage:  var('x y z')
sage:  f = vector([x, -y, 0])
sage:  f.div([x, y, z])
0
sage:  f.curl([x, y, z])
(0, 0, 0)
```

They are rather nice tools to use to verify your calculations.

Note that I myself am not a mathematician, but use math as a tool constantly.  Even though I use Maple and SageMath almost exclusively to do the hard work, it only works if I know the rules and operations and methods.  Maple and SageMath and other tools are definitely not a replacement for learning the math; but when you do have a grasp on the math, they do save a lot of time, and help you avoid most errors. (They do not help you avoid *logical* errors, like applying the wrong tool or algorithm or solution method to the wrong problem; which is why there is no alternative to learning math.)